# How does a network switch affect SSH?

Tags: switch, ssh

My job requires that I have access information on multiple machines via SSH. Unfortunately, due to some ongoing remodeling, there are now more machines than there are available ethernet ports, and I no longer have access to all the machines I need. On top of that, our one man IT department is on honeymoon.

I would like to solve this problem by using a simple network switch (the ethernet part, not the honeymoon). However, I'm not sure how it would effect SSHing into each of the machines. Would the address of the machine change or do I need to configure the switch in some way?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4, and networks not under your direct control, are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH is an application protocol running on top of layer 4 TCP. A switch basically works at layer 2, so it doesn't affect SSH at all (unless it has higher layer features that do affect IP, TCP or even higher).

If the network is flat (i.e. without VLAN trunking which would be unlikely for an edge port) you don't have to configure anything - neither IP nor MAC addresses will change. You should however check your company policy whether you're allowed to attach network equipment if it's not your job.

Comment: Yes. double check the "allowed section"... and use a really basic switch if you don't know what your are doing (no spanning-tree : it can become the new master), no dhcp server (i've already see that)... Reuse of an old configured switch put some mess.